# MySQL Connector methods `fetchone` and `fetchmany` are not PEP 249 compliant

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector, pep

With [Python 3.6.2](https://www.python.org/downloads/) and [MySQL Connector 2.1.6](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysql-connector/2.1.6) package on Windows 10, not calling the `execute` method of a database cursor, or calling it on a *non* `SELECT` statement (`CREATE`, `DROP`, `ALTER`, `INSERT`, `DELETE`, `UPDATE`, etc.) yields the following results:

```
>>> import mysql.connector
>>> session = mysql.connector.connect(user = "root", database = "mysql")
>>> cursor = session.cursor()
>>> cursor.fetchone()
>>> cursor.fetchmany()
[]
>>> cursor.fetchall()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Maggyero\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 891, in fetchall
    raise errors.InterfaceError("No result set to fetch from.")
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: No result set to fetch from.
>>> cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE test (x INTEGER)")
>>> cursor.fetchone()
>>> cursor.fetchmany()
[]
>>> cursor.fetchall()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Maggyero\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 891, in fetchall
    raise errors.InterfaceError("No result set to fetch from.")
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: No result set to fetch from.
```

[PEP 249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) explicitly states for the `fetchone`, `fetchmany` and `fetchall` methods:

> An Error (or subclass) exception is raised if the previous call to .execute*() did not produce any result set or no call was issued yet.

**So why don't `fetchone` and `fetchmany` raise an exception like `fetchall`?**

Comment: This is legit as no call to execute was issued yet. `fetchall` is currently compliant

Comment: It works according to documentation, probably better take this issue to developers instead of stackoverflow as this was a development decision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I filed a [bug report](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=87815) on bugs.mysql.com and the bug has been fixed in MySQL Connector/Python 8.0.23.